# How to create 2 pages from reportlab using one PageTemplate?

Tags: django, django-admin, reportlab

Hi all reportlab master,

I've search the web and also here in stackoverflow but can't find a similar situation on my problem I'm trying to solve during this Holiday vacation.

In django admin, I'm trying to create an action to view my database to a specific format. If I select one record I can view the report in one page pdf. Which is fine. In case the user try to more record that's where the problem start. For example I select multiple record, I can view the report but all content is still in one page pdf.

Is there a way to show a record per page in pdf? All reportlab master jedi, Please help me how to do this the right way.

Here's my code on what I did.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import LatestRsl    
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse


try:
from cStringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
from StringIO import StringIO

from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, PageTemplate, Paragraph, Frame
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

def go(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename = testframe.pdf'

    buffer = StringIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    doc = BaseDocTemplate(buffer, showBoundary=1, leftMargin= 0.1*inch, rightMargin= 0.1*inch,
                     topMargin= 0.1*inch, bottomMargin= 0.1*inch)

    signfr = Frame(5.1*inch, 1.2*inch, 2.8*inch, 0.44*inch, showBoundary=1)
    modelfr = Frame(3.6*inch, 4.6*inch, 2.8*inch, 0.44*inch, showBoundary=1)
    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id= 'rsl_frame', frames=[signfr, modelfr]),
                         PageTemplate(id= 'rsl_frame2', frames=[signfr, modelfr])])

    story = []

    styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Verdana9', fontName= 'Verdana', fontSize= 9))
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='VerdanaB10', fontName= 'VerdanaB', fontSize= 10))

    for obj in queryset:
        #1st frame
        model = Paragraph(obj.make,styles["Verdana9"])
        story.append(model)
        modelfr.addFromList(story,c)

        #2nd frame
        signatory = Paragraph(obj.signatory,styles["VerdanaB10"])
        story.append(signatory)
        signfr.addFromList(story,c)

    doc.build(story)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)
return response
```

Comment: You can insert page brake objects between the paragraphs in the story to get a multi page document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `queryset` variable contains all the records you need, you could insert a `PageBreak` object. Just add `from  reportlab.platypus import PageBreak` to the top of your file, then append a `PageBreak` object to your document's elements.

If you want to change the template for each page, you can also append a `NextPageTemplate` and pass the `id` of your `PageTemplate`. You'll need to add `from reportlab.platypus import NextPageTemplate` to the top of your file as well.

```
for obj in queryset:
    #1st frame
    model = Paragraph(obj.make,styles["Verdana9"])
    story.append(model)
    modelfr.addFromList(story,c)

    #2nd frame
    signatory = Paragraph(obj.signatory,styles["VerdanaB10"])
    story.append(signatory)
    signfr.addFromList(story,c)

    # Force the report to use a different PageTemplate on the next page
    story.append(NextPageTemplate('rsl_frame2'))
    # Start a new page for the next object in the query
    story.append(PageBreak())
```

You could move the `PageBreak` wherever you need it, but it's a simple "function" flowable. `NextPageTemplate` can take the `id` of any valid `PageTemplate` object that you've added via `addPageTemplates`.